# Scalacheck json and case classes

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

I'm writing a service that takes a case class and serializes it to json, that I will then send to an instance running Elastic Search.

I'd like scalacheck to generate several case classes, with random missing data, like this:

```
val searchDescAndBrand = SearchEntry("", "Ac Adapters", "Sony", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", 0L)
val searchBrand = SearchEntry("", ", "Sony", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", 0L)
val searchPartNumberAndBrand = SearchEntry("02DUYT", "", "Sony", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", 0L)
```

you get the idea, either fill in the values or leave them empty (the last one is a `Long` type.

This is the easy part, the problem is that the generated json doesn't just omit the "filed", but omits a whole section, for example:

```
    """
  |{
  |  "from" : 0,
  |  "size" : 10,
  |  "query" : {
  |    "bool" : {
  |      "must" : [
  |        {"match" : {
  |          "description" : {
  |            "query" : "Ac Adapters",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }},
  |        {"match" : {
  |          "brand" : {
  |            "query" : "Sony",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }}
  |      ]
  |    }
  |  }
  |}
  |
""".stripMargin)
```

if I had a case class with the first 3 fields with data, the json would be:

```
    """
  |{
  |  "from" : 0,
  |  "size" : 10,
  |  "query" : {
  |    "bool" : {
  |      "must" : [
  |        {"match" : {
  |          "part_number" : {
  |            "query" : "02D875",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }},
  |        {"match" : {
  |          "description" : {
  |            "query" : "Ac Adapters",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }},
  |        {"match" : {
  |          "brand" : {
  |            "query" : "Sony",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }}
  |      ]
  |    }
  |  }
  |}
  |
""".stripMargin)
```

So, in short, having a value means adding

```
{"match" : {
  |          "<specific name here, based on which value we have>" : {
  |            "query" : "<value from scalacheck>",
  |            "type" : "phrase"
  |          }
  |        }}
```

to the result.

How would you handle such a use case?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but you can generate nested case classes and serialize them to json, for example using sjson.

Comment: Let's see if I can clarify, I don't have a problem serializing them, my problem is writing tests for my one method that takes a case class and gives me plain json. Now I have a set of seed case classes, and a corresponding set of resulting json values, and that's how I'm testing my app, but I clearly will not cover all the possible combinations that way, so I would like to use scalacheck to generate the seed data.

Comment: You can write a custom scalacheck generator for your seed classes, however it would be best to generate (seed class, expected json) pairs, which is not straightforward because you want to test the json transformation itself?

Comment: that's correct, and if on my generators I add my current logic to generate the json, well, I'm not gaining anything, as a bug would produce both times the same "wrong" json. For now I went ahead with testing the generation of each "small" json piece, which gets me pretty far on my testing, but I'll leave this open in case someone else comes up with a clean way to test this.  Thanks!